# Pandas Series concat raises error

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, series

I do not understand what is going on here:

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['A', 'B', 'C'], name='s1')
s2 = pd.Series([4,5,6], index=['A', 'B', 'D'], name='s2')
```

while

```
pd.concat([s1, s2])
```

gives

```
A    1
B    2
C    3
A    4
B    5
D    6
```

but

```
pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
```

gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 690, in concat
verify_integrity=verify_integrity)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 749, in __init__
 self.new_axes = self._get_new_axes()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 876, in _get_new_axes
 new_axes[self.axis] = concat_axis
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

my pandas version is '0.7.0'. Can that be a problem?

Comment: Works in pandas version `0.14.1` I suggest you upgrade and try again

Comment: Looks like the version of the pandas is indeed the culprit. When I ran it on version '0.12.0', it actually did the join correctly.